# how to display size of stack after all operations

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

I have stuck in a problem where I have to display the size of the stack after all operations using an array

I am not getting any proper logic for displaying the size of the stack after all operations
all I am getting is the traversing codes to display stack elements.
but not the one for size after operations.

```c
for (i = TOP - 1; i >= 0; i--) // for traversing stack
{
    printf("\n%d",stack[i]);
}
```

it should display size of the stack after all operations are done i.e `push()` and `pop()`.

Comment: Could you give the declaration of `stack`?

Comment: What is the “size” of the stack? The number of items on the stack? That is just `TOP`. (Because, from the small amount of code you provided, it looks like you implemented a stack in an array with zero as the first item and `TOP` as the number of items in the stack, so `TOP-1` is the index of the top item on the stack.) If there is some other meaning to the “size” of the stack, you have to define it.

Comment: Requires editing IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply the size of one element by the amount of elements in the stack:

```
totalSize = stack.size() * sizeof(stack.top());
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil whoops, true!

Comment: `stack.size` and `stack.top` are C++ things. This is a C question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah i mean unless OP clarifies what exactly `stack` actually is those are sort of just meant as analogies to however he could retrieve the size or top of stack.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is, you can keep another stack that consists of the top element as the size of your stack, parallel to it, say(size_stack). Every time you push something into your stack, get the top of size_stack, increment it and push it to the size_stack. Similarly, at every pop, pop both the stacks together. This way you can get the size of your stack at every operation without iteration. Space =>  O(element) and Time => O(operation)